# CSS - unnecessary horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

On my WordPress based website there is a unnecessary horizonzal Scrollbar. How can I get rid of it?
I checked the CSS looking for margins but didn't find any.

Link: http://www.onehourleft.de/tatort/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ".slideshow_container" is wider than window width. 
After window resize, scrollbar is not showing any more. Try to look for solution in your slideshow plugin.

Or try to add to "#room-slideshow" css style: "overflow:hidden;".

Comment: The ".slideshow_container" has a style attribute with width of my browser window. How did u figuere out that ".slideshow_container" is wider than window width?

Comment: I've checked it in developer console in chrome (FireBug for mozilla). overflow:hidden for "#room-slideshow" will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Aww I know now the reason: 
The slideshow plugin calculates the width of the slides to display them. But when I have enough vertical content for a vertical scrollbar the calcuted width should be:

initial width - scollbar width

But how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
$(function() { var width = window.innerWidth; $(".slides").css('max-width',width); })
```

Or, the simplest `body {overflow-x:hidden}`

Comment: Like Macias wrote, the plugin recalculates the width on window-resize. Maybe it is possible to force the system to recalculate this with value somehow?

Comment: try body{overflow-x:hidden}, it should prevent the scrollbar. Will it cut a piece of your imgs? Yes, but just a little one.

Comment: IT's not a good solution for me because the vertical alignment of content doesn't match anymore (design issue)